# How to avoid page refresh in Firefox? It's not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, firefox

I am calling  href and onclick function, in onclick function I am calling an AJAX function. Due to page reload the AJAX function is not working in Firefox. How can I resolve this problem? Below is shown button to call controller method in href and AJAX function in onclick.

```
<a ref="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/DepartmentUser/departmentUserLoginJnlp?userId=${userId}&var=sign&siteName=${siteName}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm themebutton captureSign" type="button" id="captureSign" onclick="ajaxAsyncRequest()">Capture Signing Certificate Details</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

onclick="ajaxAsyncRequest()"

to

onclick="ajaxAsyncRequest(); return false;"

Answer (score 0):

Once the page navigates, all running scripts are stopped and AJAX calls are cancelled. If you want the AJAX call to complete, you need to delay navigation until after it's completed. A `<button>` nested in an `<a>` element is not going to work for this.

If it's an option, I would suggest putting the href call in the AJAX function, and drop the  tag. If you need the URL filled in by jsp, put it in a hidden field.

Something like this (using jQuery):

```
<button ... onClick="ajaxSyncRequest()">...</button>
<input type="hidden" id="myNextUrl" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/DepartmentUser/departmentUserLoginJnlp?userId=${userId}&var=sign&siteName=${siteName}"/>
<script>
function ajaxSyncRequest() {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    onSuccess: function () {
      window.location.href = $("#myNextUrl").val();
    }
  });
}
</script>
```